# trying to add title to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Please pardon my ignorance, I'm a total newbie to programming. I'm trying to add a title at the top of the screen to a horizontal view swiping section of my android app.  I think I'm supposed to put:

```
 setTitle("title goes here");
```

somewhere in the code below but I'm not sure how/where?

here is the code for the first fragment:

```
 import com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;


 public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState){

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, null);


}


 }
```

Comment: paste the code of your `fragment_1.xml` file, it must have the element where the title would be assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Fragment has to be 'hosted' by an Activity, try this

```
getActivity().setTitle("SumTingWong");
```